# How to use multiple attributes in algolia search using Django . Show multiple courses

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, search, algolia

How to use multiple attributes in algolia search using Django . Show multiple courses

```
    {
  "course_": [
    {
      "interest_min": 11,
      "other_fees": 0,
      "tution_fees": 56000,
      "interest_max": 14,
      "duration_max": 7,
      "payment_month_min": 4573,
      "total": 56000,
      "payment_month_max": 2567,
      "course_name": "Mtech",
      "hostel_fees": 0,
      "duration_min": 5,
      "course_type": "Full Time",
      "duration": "4"
    },
    {
      "interest_min": 7,
      "other_fees": 465,
      "tution_fees": 35456,
      "interest_max": 14,
      "duration_max": 5,
      "payment_month_min": 2414,
      "total": 41385,
      "payment_month_max": 483,
      "course_name": "Mca",
      "hostel_fees": 5464,
      "duration_min": 2,
      "course_type": "Full Time",
      "duration": "2"
    }
  ],
  "name": "A. K. Choudhury School Of Information Technology, Kolkata",
  "slug": "a-k-choudhury-school-of-information-technology-kolkata",
  "country": "India",
  "location_type": "Domestic",
  "type": "College",
  "address": "Kolkata",
  "image": "images/a-k-choudhury-school-of-information-technology-kolkata_M9cCiHQ.jpg",
  "institute_type": "Private",
  "cities": "noida",
  "college_facilities": "Sports    Transportation",
  "approved_by": "University Of Calcutta, Kolkata",
  "established": "2005-01-05",
  "state": "Up",
  "objectID": "2"
}
```

How to use multiple attributes in algolia search using Django . Show multiple courses 
using instantsearch.js in django

[image]

Comment: Hi Nitesh, I don't get your question. What do you mean by `use multiple attributes`? Do you mean _search in several attributes_? Or do you mean find a *School* by searching for the course attributes, like finding `A. K. Choudhury School` when searching for `Mtech`?

Comment: Thanks for reply  @PLNech I want to print multiple courses on search result   http://52.66.139.3:4151/

Comment: are you using [Django's search](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-django#search-1) and displaying the results, or do you mean to use **instantsearch.js** in your frontend?

Comment: backend in Django or frontend Instantsearch.js(Algolia Search)

Comment: _search.addWidget(
        instantsearch.widgets.hits({
          container: '#result',
    hitsPerPage: 9,
          templates: {
            empty:noTemplate,
            item: hitTemplate,
          }
        })
      );

Answer (score 0):

- If you are searching **from your Django back-end**, you should use the [raw_search](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-django#search-1) method to search within your data and get the corresponding JSON.
  You can then loop over the `course_` attribute to display the school's courses:

[image: Courses for Choudhury school]

- On the other hand, if you want to search from **your frontend with instantsearch.js**, you should follow the [Getting Started Guide](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/getting-started.html): have a look at the [Display Results](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/getting-started.html#display-results) section which explains how you can use a `Mustache` template to display all the attributes you want from your records.